# Google Chrome webkit notifications revoke permission? Toggle on/off?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webkit

I have webkit notifications working perfectly but I'd like to allow the user the option to switch them off should they find them annoying.

I've searched the API but can't find anything to do with revoking the permission.

Basically something that would look like the following...

```
<input type="button" onclick="window.webkitNotifications.requestPermission();" value="Yes" />
<input type="button" onclick="window.webkitNotifications.revokePermission();" value="No" />
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't revoke notification permissions, they can be revoked only using chrome configuration per page basis
Settings » Advanced settings » Privacy settings » Content settings » Notifications.

If you don't want to display them you will need to track users choice and not to create notifications, instead of revoking permissions.

Here is chromium api :

```
interface NotificationCenter {
 // Notification factory methods.
 Notification createNotification(in DOMString iconUrl, in DOMString title, in DOMString body) throws(Exception);
 optional Notification createHTMLNotification(in DOMString url) throws(Exception);

 // Permission values
 const unsigned int PERMISSION_ALLOWED = 0;
 const unsigned int PERMISSION_NOT_ALLOWED = 1;
 const unsigned int PERMISSION_DENIED = 2;

 // Permission methods
 int checkPermission();
 void requestPermission(in Function callback);
}
```